# Jquery Ajax beforeSend loading animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Hi everyone i have one problem with my ajax loading animation. The problem is when i hover any image the loading animation active under all images.

Like this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sw4ev8b4/10/)**

I want to make when i hover first image then `.ajax-loading` activated for only that image. and if i hover second image then `.ajax-loading` active for only second image ext..

Anyone can help me here ?
CSS

```
.ajax-loading {
    transition: all 0.3s;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;    
}

.ajax-loading.active {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

and AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    function showProfileTooltip(e, id) {
        //send id & get info from get_profile.php 
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: response,
                delay: 0
            },
            method: 'post',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.ajax-loading').addClass('active');    
            },
            success: function (returnHtml) {
                e.find('.user-container').empty().html(returnHtml).promise().done(function () {
                    $('.the-container').addClass('loaded');
                });
            }
        }).complete(function() {
            $('.ajax-loading').removeClass('active');    
        });

    }

    function hideProfileTooltip() {
        $('.the-container').removeClass('loaded');
    }
    $('.the-container').hover(function (e) {

        var id = $(this).find('.summary').attr('data-id');
        showProfileTooltip($(this), id);

    }, function () {
        hideProfileTooltip();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `beforeSend` function activate the class `active` for all the elements with the class `.ajax-loading`.

Since you're passing the jQuery object that is receiving the hover to the function, you can take advantage of that and add the class `active` only to those elements with the class `.ajax-loading` under it.

```
beforeSend: function() {
    $('.ajax-loading',e).addClass('active');// Note the ,e that I added
},
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sw4ev8b4/11/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did not see it. Thank you.